# Is it not supported using postman/C# HTTPRequest only to use the Authorization code flow and Azureb2C?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to use postman ( or curl for that matter ) to use the auth code flow and Azure b2c

I am following the following article by MSFT

[Auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow)

Am I misunderstanding that I should be able to use postman GET/POST only in order to follow that flow?

It is a bit confusing to say the least.

I have an API protected by AzureB2C and it works fine with the login etc using the browser but I cannot reproduce a working scenario using postman or MSAL without using the ROPC flow which I want to avoid as it is deemed insecure by most.

Can I achieve the authorization code flow using GET/POST in postman only or C# simple HTTPRequests?

Answer (score 0):

No, authorization code flow requires interaction in a browser.

ROPC and Client credentials flow are the usual flows used for non-interactive access.

If you are using Postman, you can use authorization code flow totally fine since it supports it.
I actually made an article on that: https://joonasw.net/view/testing-azure-ad-protected-apis-part-2-postman.

Comment: ok I am worried about the ROPC flow, seems the common conclusion is that it is not safe so I am a bit confused as to what to implement in my mobile app, iOS and Android, can they not use interactive flows?

Comment: Mobile apps can totally use interactive flows, through system browser or embedded web view.

Comment: I tried to google, seems I need to make a small test app in swift or something to test MSAL to make this working, the documentation is so not clear though, very confusing

Comment: In your post, explain exactly what you’re running in POSTMan and exactly the error or issue you are getting. You must run the GET to /authorize in the browser. The POST to redeem an Auth Code can be run in POSTMan.